# varnish service has failed to start

Tags: varnish

Trying to install varnish on cpanel+cloudlinux VPS but can't start the software.
varnish.service has failed.

```
$varnishd -V varnishd
```

> (varnish-6.0.8 revision 97e54ada6ac578af332e52b44d2038bb4fa4cd4a)
> Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS Copyright (c) 2006-2020 Varnish
> Software AS

try to start varnish...

```
$systemctl start varnish
```

> Job for varnish.service failed because the control process exited with
> error code. See "systemctl status varnish.service" and "journalctl
> -xe" for details.

my apache is listed on port 8080...

```
$netstat -pnltu

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      656/exim
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1272/memcached
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1275/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2095            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      337953/cpsrvd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1499/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1275/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      830454/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2096            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      337953/cpsrvd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      656/exim
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1290/pdns_server
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1276/pure-ftpd (SER
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      656/exim
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1290/pdns_server
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      830454/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38908           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1225059/checkstatus
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2077            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2364/cpdavd - accep
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2078            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2364/cpdavd - accep
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2079            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2364/cpdavd - accep
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2364/cpdavd - accep
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1275/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2082            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      337953/cpsrvd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2083            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      337953/cpsrvd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:579           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1939/cPhulkd - proc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1275/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2086            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      337953/cpsrvd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36454           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5439/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2087            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      337953/cpsrvd
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1215674/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      656/exim
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      656/exim
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      1290/pdns_server
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      1276/pure-ftpd (SER
tcp6       0      0 :::4949                 :::*                    LISTEN      749/perl
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      656/exim
tcp6       0      0 :::36454                :::*                    LISTEN      5439/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           1290/pdns_server
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           571/chronyd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*                           1272/memcached
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                1290/pdns_server
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                571/chronyd
```

mY Varnish status...

```
$systemctl status varnish.service
```

> varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; disabled;
> vendor preset: disabled) Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri
> 2021-10-08 08:32:43 IDT; 5min ago   Process: 1498287
> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -a localhost:8443,PROXY -p
> feature=+http2 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,256m
> (code=exited, status=255)

and My /etc/varnish/default.vcl file...

```
$cat /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

> backend default {
> .host = "127.0.0.1";
> .port = "8080";}

```
$journalctl -xe
```

> Oct 11 18:54:19 server1. varnishd[1765617]: Update your VCL to
> Version 4 Oct 11 18:54:19 server1. varnishd[1765617]: vcl 4.1;
> Oct 11 18:54:19 server1. varnishd[1765617]: on the first line
> of the VCL Oct 11 18:54:19 server1. varnishd[1765617]:
> ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Oct 11 18:54:19 server1.
> varnishd[1765617]: backend default { Oct 11 18:54:19 server1.
> varnishd[1765617]: #######---------- Oct 11 18:54:19 server1.
> varnishd[1765617]: Running VCC-compiler failed, Oct 11 18:54:19
> server1. varnishd[1765617]: VCL compilation failed Oct 11
> 18:54:19 server1. systemd[1]: varnish.service: control process
> ex Oct 11 18:54:19 server1. systemd[1]: Failed to start
> Varnish Cache, a hi Subject: Unit varnish.service has failed
> Defined-By: systemd Support:
> http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel Unit
> varnish.service has failed. The result is failed. Oct 11 18:54:19
> server1. systemd[1]: Unit varnish.service entered failed Oct
> 11 18:54:19 server1. systemd[1]: varnish.service failed. Oct
> 11 18:54:19 server1. polkitd[533]: Unregistered Authentication
> Agent Oct 11 18:54:24 server1. dovecot[506582]: lmtp(1764533):
> Connect from lo Oct 11 18:54:24 server1. dovecot[506582]:
> lmtp(develop@wordwpressplugins Oct 11 18:54:24 server1.
> dovecot[506582]: lmtp(1764533): Disconnect from

Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My assumption

The following error message stands out:

```
Oct 11 18:54:19 server1. varnishd[1765617]: Update your VCL to Version 4
```

It refers to the fact that you didn't specify a VCL version in your VCL file.

### My tests return a different error:

However, when it test it with an AWS instance that runs https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-ptcusqlqcvvki?sr=0-2&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWSMPContessa, I get the following error:

```
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: Error:
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: Message from VCC-compiler:
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: VCL version declaration missing
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: Update your VCL to Version 4 syntax, and add
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]:         vcl 4.1;
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: on the first line of the VCL files.
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 1 Pos 1)
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: backend default {
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: #######----------
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
Oct 12 08:06:33  varnishd[44646]: VCL compilation failed
Oct 12 08:06:33  systemd[1]: varnish.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Oct 12 08:06:33  systemd[1]: varnish.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

As you can see, my CloudLinux 8 cPanel instance on AWS returns a more specific error message.

### How to fix

Since Varnish 4, a VCL version label was introduced. You need to specify it at the start of your VCL file.

Here's how I would refactor your example:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default { 
    .host = "127.0.0.1"; 
    .port = "8080";
}
```

> I'm using `vcl 4.1;` as the VCL version label because you are running Varnish 6. Earlier versions of Varnish only support `vcl 4.0;`

Comment: Thank u very very much for your help. as you suggested I added the "vcl 4.1;" line to the /etc/varnish/default.vcl solved the issue. now I can start Varnish with no issue.